# Low performance with ethernet bridge

Tags: networking, performance, network-bridge

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server with 2 NICs, both of which are part of (separate) bridges and one of them also handles VLANs. It connects to a managed switch and finally into a trunk port on my firewall (OPNsense). `br0` just bridges into my primary LAN (VLAN-less) and `br1` is part of a VLAN with tag 13. I also have another VLAN (tag 2) that goes directly over the physical interface used by `br1`.

Now, when I'm running a speed test (Ookla's) through the different interfaces, this happens:

```
$ (speedtest -s 43267 -I br0; speedtest -s 43267 -I br1; speedtest -s 43267 -I vlan2) | grep -E '(Latency|Download|Upload|Packet Loss)'
    Latency:    10.83 ms   (2.03 ms jitter)
   Download:   136.67 Mbps (data used: 160.7 MB )
     Upload:    30.44 Mbps (data used: 15.2 MB )
Packet Loss:     0.0%

    Latency:    11.32 ms   (3.09 ms jitter)
   Download:   155.42 Mbps (data used: 183.3 MB )
     Upload:    30.37 Mbps (data used: 14.5 MB )
Packet Loss:     0.0%

    Latency:    11.91 ms   (9.06 ms jitter)
   Download:   294.56 Mbps (data used: 393.4 MB )
     Upload:    29.76 Mbps (data used: 13.4 MB )
Packet Loss:     0.0%
```

I picked this particular server because I've always been able to get consistent results from it. My ISP gives me 300/30 and when using the `vlan2` interface I'm consistently getting 290+ download. But as you can see, anything that goes through a bridge barely gets half of that. I know that Ookla's speed test may not be considered a "good" test, but it does sometimes feel like the NIC is sluggish because SSHing into the box (which goes through `br0`) sometimes isn't quite instantaneous. And even then, why would Ookla's test **consistently** reach about half the available bandwidth? This leads me to believe there actually **is** something wrong with the bridges. Let's also not forget that the last 2 results used the same physical interface, so it's not a cabling/hardware issue.

Furthermore, both `iptables` and `ebtables` are set to just `ACCEPT` everything. I'm not sure if `ebtables` is even being used because there should be 3 default tables but I only have `filter`. `lsmod` also doesn't show anything for `eb` (I think the module is called `ebt` or something?).

The relevant parts from `lshw`:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:85:c2:31:6d:b1
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 4-1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:dc200000-dc21ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:dc220000-dc223fff

  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: 70:85:c2:31:6d:b3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:144 memory:dc500000-dc51ffff
```

The `enp0s31f6` interface is used by `br0`, so `enp6s0` is for `br1` (over `vlan13`) and `vlan2`. One thing that might complicate it further: the NICs use completely different drivers (`igb` vs `e1000e`) and **both** have the same issue. The driver firmwares seem to be loaded properly too. When I check `sysctl -a | grep -F .br1` and `... | grep -F .vlan2` all the values are **exactly** the same. I only did a few sysctl tweaks anyways:

```
# Reverse path fltering (0 = disabled, 1 = strict, 2 = loose)
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s31f6.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.br0.rp_filter = 1

# VLAN interfaces should do loose checking
net.ipv4.conf.enp6s0.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.vlan2.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.vlan13.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.br1.rp_filter = 2

# Disable IPv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.enp0s31f6.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.enp6s0.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.br0.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.br1.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.vlan2.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.vlan13.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And finally, `uname -pr`: `5.4.0-113-generic x86_64`.

I did notice `enp6s0` used the `mq` scheduler/discipline while `enp0s31f6` was using `fq_codel`. Switching them around didn't change one thing though, and since they're different drivers I suppose seeing different schedulers isn't all that unexpected. I also found some interesting bugs about bridges and the **e1000e** driver, but since I'm also having issues with **igb** I don't think those would be relevant to the problem here. When this server was on Ubuntu 18.04 with the same network setup I definitely could saturate my ISP, they only gave me 250/25 back then and the test would usually show 240+. So I'm thinking either something changed about how bridges are handled, or some system parameter's default setting was changed and that doesn't play well with my setup, or there is in fact a(nother) bug in the drivers.

My interfaces are managed by networkd (via netplan) by the way. I would add the YAML files but I think the description is pretty clear and it's already quite the wall of text. :> If needed I can always edit them in, of course.

What could be the cause of my bridges being relatively low-performing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, i found that pings through the bridge would fail while doing a speed test etc.

upping the mtu to 9000 fixed things for me, now ping latency barely changes while speedtest downloads at 500mbps, note in my case i only amended mtu br1 which is my inside interface, br0 is connected to a router that only does mtu of 1500 & upping interface mtu gives worse performance.

to see bridge interface mtu's

```
bridge link
```

My netplan /etc/netplan/xxxxx.yml

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      mtu:  9000
      dhcp4:  no
    ens192:
      mtu:  1500
      dhcp4:  no
    ens224:
      mtu:  1500
      dhcp4:  no
    ens256:
      mtu:  9000
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4:  true
      interfaces:
        -  ens192
        -  ens224
    br1:
      dhcp4:  true
      interfaces:
        -  ens160
        -  ens256
  version: 2
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately changing the MTU doesn't seem to matter, the performance stays about the same. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you restart net plan and restart the service? 

https://vitux.com/how-to-configure-networking-with-netplan-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Of course. ;] I verified the interface was actually using an MTU of 9000 before running the speedtest again.